# How to pass number of "column names" and "values" for a where claues for a select query in a stored procedure dynamically..?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_attendee (
    out_chr_err_code   OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_chr_err_msg    OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_attendee_tab   OUT                return_attendee_arr_result,
    in_from_date       IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_to_date         IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_location        IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_keys            char_array,
    in_values          char_array
) IS

    l_chr_srcstage        VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_biqtab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_srctab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_bistagtab       VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_err_code        VARCHAR2(255);
    l_chr_err_msg         VARCHAR2(255);
    l_out_chr_errbuf      VARCHAR2(2000);
    lrec                  return_attendee_report;
    l_num_counter         NUMBER := 0;
    l_sort_column         VARCHAR2(30) := lower(in_sort_column);
    l_order_by            VARCHAR2(10) := lower(in_order_by);
    l_location_id         VARCHAR2(256) := in_location;
    l_start_row           NUMBER := l_start_row_num;
    l_end_row             NUMBER := l_end_row_num;
    l_keys                char_array := in_keys;
    l_values              char_array := in_values;
    CURSOR cur_attendee_data IS
    SELECT
        r.id              request_id,
        TO_CHAR(a.event_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') startdate,
        r.customer_name   customer_name,
        r.country         country,
        r.duration        duration,
        r.customer_name   ext_att_customer_company,
        c.first_name      ext_att_first_name,
        c.last_name       ext_att_last_name
    FROM
        bi_request r
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_activity_day a ON a.request_id = r.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_catering_activity b ON b.request_activity_day_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_attendees c ON c.request_id = r.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_act_day_room d ON d.request_activity_day_id = a.id
                                               AND d.room = b.room
    WHERE
        r.state = 'CONFIRMED'
        AND a.event_date BETWEEN l_start_date AND l_end_date
        AND r.location_id = l_location_id
        AND country IN (
            SELECT
                column_value
            FROM
                TABLE ( l_values
                --dynamic array here
                 )
        )
        AND room IN (
            SELECT
                column_value
            FROM
                TABLE ( l_values
            --dynamic array here
                 )
        )
        -- like the above where clause condition I need to add columns and values dynamically ;
        ;

    TYPE rec_attendee_data IS
        TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_cur_attendee_data   rec_attendee_data;
BEGIN
out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result();
OPEN cur_attendee_data;
LOOP
  FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;
  EXIT WHEN l_cur_attendee_data.count = 0;
  dbms_output.put_line('here in first insert');
  lrec := return_attendee_report();
  out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result(return_attendee_report());
  out_attendee_tab.DELETE;
   FOR i IN 1..l_cur_attendee_data.count LOOP
  BEGIN
  l_num_counter := l_num_counter + 1;
  lrec := return_attendee_report();
  lrec.requestid := l_cur_attendee_data(i).request_id;
  --some code here
  IF l_num_counter > 1 THEN
  out_attendee_tab.extend();
  out_attendee_tab(l_num_counter) := return_attendee_report();
  ELSE
  out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result(return_attendee_report());
  END IF;
  out_attendee_tab(l_num_counter) := lrec;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Error occurred : ' || sqlerrm);
            END;
        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

I need to add filters dynamically, a user has to pass column names and values for each filed. how to map column name with values array.

Input for example:

```
 {'column_1,value1,value2,value3',
  'column_2,value1,value2,value3',
  'column_3,value1,value2,value3'}
```

How to handle it dynamically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: need to add no of columns with different values for each column in where Clause. or else can we use JSON object here..?

Comment: How you planned to identify that the item in your array is column name or value of that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_json_to_array (
    json_doc    IN          VARCHAR2,
    in_column   IN          VARCHAR2
) RETURN char_array AS

    x               char_array;
    company_array   VARCHAR2(100);
    varpath         VARCHAR2(30);
    v_query_str     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    varpath := in_column;
    v_query_str := 'SELECT
        JSON_VALUE('''
                   || json_doc
                   || ''',  ''$.'
                   || varpath
                   || ''')
    FROM
        dual';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    INTO company_array;
    SELECT
        fn_varchar_to_array(company_array)
    INTO x
    FROM
        dual;

    RETURN x;
END fn_json_to_array;
```

By passing JSON as a string and convert it as an array.
EX:-json_doc := '{
          "country"      : "India,American Samoa",
          "room"      : "101",
}';

Answer (score 0):

You can try and open a cursor for a dynamic query as a String.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_attendee (
    out_chr_err_code   OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_chr_err_msg    OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_attendee_tab   OUT                return_attendee_arr_result,
    in_from_date       IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_to_date         IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_location        IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_keys            char_array,
    in_values          char_array
) IS

    l_chr_srcstage        VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_biqtab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_srctab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_bistagtab       VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_err_code        VARCHAR2(255);
    l_chr_err_msg         VARCHAR2(255);
    l_out_chr_errbuf      VARCHAR2(2000);
    lrec                  return_attendee_report;
    l_num_counter         NUMBER := 0;
    l_sort_column         VARCHAR2(30) := lower(in_sort_column);
    l_order_by            VARCHAR2(10) := lower(in_order_by);
    l_location_id         VARCHAR2(256) := in_location;
    l_start_row           NUMBER := l_start_row_num;
    l_end_row             NUMBER := l_end_row_num;
    l_keys                char_array := in_keys;
    l_values              char_array := in_values;
    CURSOR cur_attendee_data SYS_REFCURSOR;


    TYPE rec_attendee_data IS
        TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_cur_attendee_data   rec_attendee_data;

    v_query CLOB; --> You can declare even as VARCHAR2 if you know that the size of the query will not increase
BEGIN
    out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result();

    v_query := 'SELECT
        r.id              request_id,
        TO_CHAR(a.event_date, ''MM/DD/YYYY'') startdate,
        r.customer_name   customer_name,
        r.country         country,
        r.duration        duration,
        r.customer_name   ext_att_customer_company,
        c.first_name      ext_att_first_name,
        c.last_name       ext_att_last_name
    FROM
        bi_request r
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_activity_day a ON a.request_id = r.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_catering_activity b ON b.request_activity_day_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_attendees c ON c.request_id = r.id
        LEFT JOIN bi_request_act_day_room d ON d.request_activity_day_id = a.id
                                               AND d.room = b.room
    WHERE
        r.state = ''CONFIRMED''
        AND a.event_date BETWEEN l_start_date AND l_end_date
        AND r.location_id = l_location_id
        AND country IN (
            SELECT
                '|| column_value || '
            FROM
                TABLE ( l_values
                '|| dynamic_array_here || '
                 )
        )
        AND room IN (
            SELECT
                '|| column_value || '
            FROM
                TABLE ( l_values
            '|| dynamic_array_here || '
                 )
        )';

    OPEN cur_attendee_data FOR v_query;
    LOOP
      FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;
      EXIT WHEN l_cur_attendee_data.count = 0;
      dbms_output.put_line('here in first insert');
      lrec := return_attendee_report();
      out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result(return_attendee_report());
      out_attendee_tab.DELETE;
       FOR i IN 1..l_cur_attendee_data.count LOOP
      BEGIN
      l_num_counter := l_num_counter + 1;
      lrec := return_attendee_report();
      lrec.requestid := l_cur_attendee_data(i).request_id;
      --some code here
      IF l_num_counter > 1 THEN
      out_attendee_tab.extend();
      out_attendee_tab(l_num_counter) := return_attendee_report();
      ELSE
      out_attendee_tab := return_attendee_arr_result(return_attendee_report());
      END IF;
      out_attendee_tab(l_num_counter) := lrec;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Error occurred : ' || sqlerrm);
                END;
            END LOOP;

        END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

***Note:** This method might drop in performance if you are using this in a transactional table.

Comment: can you give an example for input param how we need to pass here, how to maping values with columns..?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking here. What you need to do is just pass the values column_value and dynamic_array_here with the values you are planning to.